# Deploying Django project from GitHub to railway

Tags: django, github

I'm trying to deploy my Django project from GitHub to the railway(railway.app) and I keep getting a failed error during the build process (Deployment Failed during build process)

Have checked for resources to solve this but none seems to be of help, can anyone help me with this, please?

Answer (score -1):

I suggest that create private repository and not add Add a README file, after that, you will get screen to upload with terminal follow instruction.

Comment: Are you saying I use the terminal instead and not add a README file

Comment: yes, this is way of push your app to github